# difficulty ensuring old records from a database get deleted when a certain form is closed

Tags: vb.net, network-programming

My program enables user's to play online against other players. the way I achieve this is by having a lobby form with a datagridview displaying all the matches in a datatable entitled "matches". from their you can select a match (send a request) or host one which will direct you to a "waiting" form and insert your match into the database. The problem is that this database fills up fast with old matches because I have coded it to delete records on form close however this does not run if the process (whole program) is ended from say task manager and I am left with an old game in the database. my question is how can I ensure that when a user stops hosting, their corresponding match is deleted. The only solution I can think of involves having a server constantly pinging all the matches and deleting them if they do not respond.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea of the server pinging the client is a good one. But it can be reversed. For example,   by using a TCP connection, you can send the username or ID of the player to the server every two minutes through the client. If the player's client has not pinged the server in two minutes, the server can assume that the player is offline and delete the old 'match' instead of the client. You can run the server dedicated and it will always work well.

For more information on TCP data communication, just google it!

Hope this helped,

Rodit